# Stubbing Out a PayPal Account?

Tags: php, payment, paypal

Is there tool for testing an application that uses the PayPal account API without actually using the live PayPal account and API?

Sort of like Unit Testing the application (doesn't actually transfer the money but the application calling the API thinks it does anyway)

(I'm using PHP and Wordpress)

Comment: there's paypal sandbox that you can use to simulate https://developer.paypal.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sandbox API.  In the developer center, you are able to generate a testing credit card number to use with the sandbox.

In the normal API, your "endpoint" looks something like this:

```
$API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.paypal.com/nvp';
```

For the sandbox, you have:

```
$API_Endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
```

Comment: Forgot about this API I never got around to trying it but hopefully this helps leeand00! :)

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm gonna go try this out.